# windowbuilder eclipse error activating bundle

Tags: c, eclipse, windowbuilder

i'm trying to install WindowBuilder on Eclipse.
I'm running it on a 10.13.1 mac.

Eclipse Oxygen.

Trying to use: http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.7/
as the download link on the "help" option on eclipse.

i get an error like this:

Problem Opening Wizard.
The selected Wizard could not be started.
Plug-in org.eclipse.wb.swing was unable to load class org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.wizards.frame.NewJFrameWizard.
An error ocurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.wb.swing(548).

i tried to install WindowBuilder on my Windows desktop. The first time i installed the Wb, i got the same error, but after that i updated the Eclipse to the latest version and installed the WB again. Worked.

Tried the same on mac, but didn't works.

Any help? please

Comment: I am getting this exact same error message whenever I try to do anything with WindowBuilder.  Looks like it is a problem with WindowBuilder and/or this version of Eclipse.  I am on Windows 10 instead of a Mac though.

Comment: Don't install it through an update site, install it through the eclipse market place found under the help menu. before you do that go to help "About eclipse" installation details" remove all window builder features, restart eclipse and install from market place.